# Is there a visual tool running on Windows that lets me display CPU load etc on Windows and Linux machines?

Tags: linux, windows, monitoring

I would like to have a real time visual status screen displaying the current CPU usage (and possibly memory consumption) for a number of remote machines. These machines will be reachable only using TCP (not UDP etc) and the graphical client will need to run on Windows. Does anyone know of such a tool?

Comment: "Real-time" is tricky. It will cause a *substantial* amount of network traffic and will require a very high-end collection server. Typically, stats like this are sampled at 5 minute intervals. Is this good enough for you or do you really need real-time?

Comment: @MDMarra, I do not need hard real time, if I could get a 1 minute average I would be happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/), [Opsview](http://www.opsview.com/), [SCOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Center_Operations_Manager), and plenty of other pieces of monitoring software can do this and will display the results in a web browser or Windows console. Keep in mind that even at 1 minute sample intervals, you'll be creating a lot of traffic and causing additional load processing the SNMP/WMI requests on the boxes being monitored. The "standard" value for samples like this are 5 minutes. You can absolutely set them to be more frequent, but be cautious.

Comment: Thank you. Can you recommend a product that is free and easy to set up? I'm looking at doing this for, initially, only a couple of boxes.

Comment: Both Opsview and Cacti are free. "Easy" is a relative term. I didn't find Cacti hard to set up, but I could imagine someone that's not comfortable in Linux or with SNMP might. Just read the install guides for a few products. You should get a feel pretty quickly. Also, this is pretty quickly turning into a "shopping" question, which is outside of the scope of Server Fault. Take a look at the [faq] if you're unsure.

Answer (score 0):

You might look into nagios http://www.nagios.org (there is both a free and paid support versions).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/). If you need notification when a some service or host become unavailable i think that Nagios is best solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If the collection server is Windows you can also look at [Spiceworks](http://spiceworks.com).  Also free.